# Get body table rows, but not table head

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table which has correct thead and tbody.I am grabbing all the table rows in a table, to process them, but unfortunately it is grabbing the header as well. Here is my code:

```
var base=$(this),$rowCells;
base.find('tr').each(function(){    
//get body text
$rowCells=$(this).children();
var $bodyText=$rowCells.map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
})
```

Ok Here is what I have tried

```
base.find('tbody tr').each(function())
```

but this goes a little crazy goes into an everlasting loop and dies in a big way.
Also tried

```
base.find('tbody > tr').each(function())
```

but again this does not work and basically crashes my browser as before.
This code isn't the only code btw but the important looping part. This is just a small part of a jquery plugin I am writing.

Just want to know how I can target the tbody instead of the thead.

I have been requested to post more code. This is my full jquery plugin. What it does is that it creates a new column and takes all the rows and puts them in the first column and hides all the other rows so that it can be viewed on a mobile phone. The plugin is working perfectly but I need to add something to it, and unfortunately the plugin is grabbing header rows where it shouldn't on the line I have marked.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#mytable1').tSquash({'pixels':'350','titleColumn':'headings w4','textColumn':'redtext'});
 $('#mytable2').tSquash({'pixels':'600','titleColumn':'headings w5'});
});


// tSquash V1.0.0
;(function($) {
 "use strict";
 $.fn.tSquash = function(options,callback) {
  var settings =$.extend(true, {},{
   'pixels':480,
   'titleColumn':"",
   'textColumn':"",
  },options);
 
 var base=$(this),$rowCells;
 

 base.resize=function()
 {
  $(window).resize(function(){
   base.change();
  });
 }
 base.change=function()
 {
  if($(window).width() < settings.pixels ){
   base.minify();
  }
  else
  {
   base.enlarge();
  }
 }
 base.minify=function()
 {
  if(base.find('th').eq(0).attr('class')!="tSquash")
  {
   var tablename = '#'+$.trim(base.attr('id'));
   // Count columns
   var columnCount = $(tablename+' thead th').length;
   // get table head text into array $myheadertext
   var $headCells = $(base).find('thead tr:first').children();
   var $myheadertext = $headCells.map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
   }).get();
    
   //This adds a column and gives it the class of tSquash  
   base.find('tr').each(function(){//This is supposed to only get body tr but it is getting header tr too
    //get body text
    $rowCells=$(this).children();
    var $bodyText=$rowCells.map(function() {
     return $(this).text();
    }).get();
    
    $(this).find('td').eq(0).before('<td></td>');
    $(this).find('th').eq(0).before('<th></th>');
    $(this).find('td').eq(0).addClass("tSquash");
    $(this).find('th').eq(0).addClass("tSquash");
   
    for(var i=0;i<columnCount;i++)
    { 
     //Add text to first column
     $(this).find('td').eq(0).append('<span class="'+settings.titleColumn+'">'+$myheadertext[i]+': </span><span class="'+settings.textColumn+'">'+$bodyText[i]+'</span></br>');
     $(this).find('td').eq(i+1).hide();
     $(this).find('th').eq(i+1).hide();
    }
    
   })
   
     
  }
 }
 base.enlarge=function()
 {
  $('.tSquash').remove();
  base.find('td').show(),base.find('th').show();
 }
 base.change();
 base.resize();
 return base;
  
 }
 
})(jQuery);
```

```css
tbody{
border: 1px solid #000; 
 
}
tbody td{
border: 1px solid #000;
padding:10px; 
}

#mytable2{
100%; 
}

.headings{
 font-weight: bolder;
 display:inline-block;
}
.redtext
{
 color:red;
}


.w4
{
 width: 4em;
}
.w5
{
 width: 5em;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
 <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
   
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
</head>

<body>
    <table id="mytable1" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
         <tr>
                <th>The</th>
                <th>First</th>
                <th>Stage</th>
                <th>Is</th>
                <th>The</th>
                <th>Hardest</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
         <tr id="t_1"><td>To</td><td>be</td><td>or</td><td>not</td><td>to</td><td>be</td></tr>
            <tr id="t_2"><td>This</td><td>I</td><td>Believe</td><td>is</td><td>the</td><td>last</td></tr>
            <tr id="t_3"><td>The</td><td>First</td><td>Stage</td><td>is</td><td>the</td><td>hardest</td></tr>
            <tr id="t_4"><td>The</td><td>First</td><td>Stage</td><td>is</td><td>the</td><td>hardest</td></tr>
            <tr id="t_5"><td>The</td><td>First</td><td>Stage</td><td>is</td><td>the</td><td>hardest</td></tr>
            <tr id="t_6"><td>The</td><td>First</td><td>Stage</td><td>is</td><td>the</td><td>hardest</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
 <div id="test"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</body>

<body>
    <table id="mytable2" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
         <tr>
                <th>I</th>
                <th>Am</th>
                <th>An</th>
                <th>Elephant</th>
                <th>Man</th>
                <th>Today</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
         <tr><td>To</td><td>be</td><td>or</td><td>not</td><td>to</td><td>be</td></tr>
            <tr><td>This</td><td>I</td><td>Believe</td><td>is</td><td>the</td><td>last</td></tr>
            <tr><td>The</td><td>First</td><td>Stage</td><td>is</td><td>the</td><td>hardest</td></tr>
            <tr><td>The</td><td>First</td><td>Stage</td><td>is</td><td>the</td><td>hardest</td></tr>
            <tr><td>The</td><td>First</td><td>Stage</td><td>is</td><td>the</td><td>hardest</td></tr>
            <tr><td>The</td><td>First</td><td>Stage</td><td>is</td><td>the</td><td>hardest</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
 <div id="test"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: You may want to post the (probably) relevant HTML. Plus, you initially tagged as php, so that might be somewhat relevant. *Just a thought*.

Comment: Yes that was an error on my part. I use php and jquery all the time, and just forgot when I added the php tag accidentally. Removed it now. As for the code there is a lot of code and some of it is sensitive.

Comment: I understand. Any way you post a (minimum) example and/or fiddle? I may not be able to help, but it could be useful for others who may be able to Thomas.

Comment: I don't mind posting my full jquery plugin as that will be downloadable by anyone anyway, but as it stands my plugin is working perfectly, but I need to add something to it which requires that it does not grab the header rows, as I am grabbing them separate. I will post my full plugin.

Comment: Have a look at Roko's answer below; you may not have to if his answer works.

Comment: What's `base.return;` in your code??

Comment: In a jQuery plugin you normally return from the plugin or it will stop other plugins running.

Comment: @ThomasWilliams that's not true. `base.return` tries to invoke a `return` method on the `base` object. Which does not exists. To keep chainability you should use `return this;` or in your case `return base;` (since `base` is your jQuery Method Element reference)

Comment: Yes it should have been return base; Damn that was a typo in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply access `tbody` it's the **correct** way to do it.

```
base.find('tbody tr').each(function(){
```

<sub>(P.S: even if you didn't specifically used the `<tbody>` element, it's added by default by the browser.)</sub>

```js
var $table = $("table"); // Or as you use it: $(this) Supposingly a table...

$table.find('tbody tr').each(function() {    
  
  var $rowCells = $(this).find("td"); // TDs of the current iterating TR
  var bodyText = $rowCells.map(function() { // Array to hold all TD text
    return $(this).text();
  }).get();
  
  // HERE Do something with `bodyText` Array,
  // otherwise will got substituted with new values
  // in the second TR iteration
  console.log( bodyText );
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">Head</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>TR1 Cell 1</td>
      <td>TR1 Cell 2</td>
      <td>TR1 Cell 3</td>
      <td>TR1 Cell 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>TR2 Cell 1</td>
      <td>TR2 Cell 2</td>
      <td>TR2 Cell 3</td>
      <td>TR2 Cell 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you are entering an infinite loop that's most probabily due to some other issues in your plugin.

Comment: See I have tried that and it caused my crash. I do have a thead and tbody in my table but it wasn't easy for me to post that without showing stuff I didn't want to show, like loads of php stuff. I have now posted full plugin. Might be a bug elseswhere like you said. My plugin does what it is supposed to but it is getting the thead when it shouldn't.

Comment: @ThomasWilliams if it's a plugin you don't need to show PHP code, simply  create a minimal table and apply your plugin to it.

Comment: @ThomasWilliams just for reference: http://jsbin.com/qodaqe/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output take a look in console at the load of JS errors you have (due to "use strict"... i.e...).

Comment: Thats an idea. But will take me a lilttle while to do it. ps not getting any errors in console in firebug

Comment: @ThomasWilliams Why you use in your code `$('.tSquash').remove();` if it's a plugin you should not target all `.tSquash` elements in the whole page!!

Comment: Yes i agree, but this is work in progress. So far I only have one table on the page. Will probably use base .tSquash later.

Comment: @ThomasWilliams may I just ask out of curiosity what is your plugin supposed to do actually?

Comment: Right my plugin is for squashing tables down for mobile phone screens. It adds a new column at the beginning of the table and takes all the other columns and put them in the first column. Then it hides all the other columns. You are then left with one column instead of many. Then on a wider screen it shows the full size table again. PS trying to work how to add my code to this page and make it work.

Comment: I have managed to add  my code to show you what it does. You have to view it full screen and squash the screen down. It will change at different width as set in the jquery. Now this work ok, but I need to add something else to the code, but what it is not only grabbing tbody but also thead in the main code if I add tbody tr. It crashes.

Comment: Just found out something interesting. If I use tbody tr and squash the screen it goes haywire, but if I refresh the screen it is ok narrow, until I move it again. I think the resize function is causing the tbody tr to go wrong. Think I am getting closer to the answer

Comment: I think I know what is going wrong. When it is minified and I move the screen it is trying to minify again, which is causing the problem. Once it is minified it should not call minify again.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. The problem wasn't in the place I thought it was, but it was being caused by another part of the code, which checked on the resizing the of page and kept calling my routine over and over again,and so this is my solution.

```
var base=$(this);
var minify=true;
```

At the start. So that my minify function only runs when it is true. When the screen size is lower than the setting it runs minify once, then sets minify to false so it doesn't run again until the screen size is bigger by doing this.

```
base.change=function()
{
    if($(window).width() < settings.pixels ){
        if(minify) base.minify();
    }
    else
    {
        base.enlarge();
    }
}
```

Then in my minify function I do this

```
base.minify=function()
    {
        minify=false;
snip
```

Then in my enlarge function I do this

```
base.enlarge=function()
{
    $('.tSquash').remove();
    base.find('td').show(),base.find('th').show();
    minify=true;
}
```

I set minify back to true.

However even thouugh this is the answer which solved my problem Roko C. Buljan  gave the correct answer to my actual question, so I will give him the tick. Thanks Roko for the help.

PS. Should I post the corrected code or what? (To help someone else I wonder)